# Laravel and Processing.js

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-5, processing.js

Does anyone have experience with the Laravel framework and Processing.js? I've recently begun working with Laravel, but it is my first experience using asset management, gulp/sass, etc. Specifically, can I just compile the Processing.js script along with everything else? It's a big library, so I don't want pages to load it that don't need it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened when you tried compiling the Processing.js script along with everything else?

Comment: Before I tried it, I wanted to determine if it will slow down the loading of pages that don't need it.

Comment: And what did you find out when you did some profiling?

Comment: I haven't learned how to do profiling in Laravel yet. (I'm a CodeIgniter refugee.)

Comment: You don't need to do anything complicated. All I'm saying is that you seem to be worrying about a problem that you don't have yet. Just try the thing you suggested (compiling Processing.js along with everything else) and see what happens.

Comment: You're right, I tend to anticipate problems before they occur. Thanks for the advice, I will give it a try. I'm so impressed with Laravel and the newer web tools that it just might turn out not be a problem at all. Thanks.